# \social not working in LaTeX

Tags: moderncv

I'm currently working on my CV and I'm using the `moderncv` template. When I try to use `\social[github]{pedrocaseiro}` I get the following errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \social
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX 
Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.... \social[


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'


\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 



\firstname{Jon} % Your first name
\familyname{Snow} % Your last name
\title{Software Engineer}
\address{123, 123}{}
\mobile{(+123) 123123123}
\email{jonsnow@thenorthemail.com}
\homepage{website}{website} 
\social[github]{123123}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using an updated `moderncv` package?

Comment: actually i think that might be it :/

Comment: Seems so, if `\social` is not recognised. You should consider updating your `moderncv` bundle. Additionally, there's another issu that I comment in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `\social` is undefined, you might be using an outdated version of `moderncv`. Please consider updating it. Besides this, there's another problem with `\homepage`; `\homepage` takes just one mandatory argument and you are using two. Change

```
\homepage{website}{website}
```

to

```
\homepage{website}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\firstname{Jon} % Your first name
\familyname{Snow} % Your last name
\title{Software Engineer}
\address{123, 123}{}
\mobile{(+123) 123123123}
\email{jonsnow@thenorthemail.com}
\homepage{website}{website} 
\social[github]{123123}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{picture} % The first bracket is the picture height

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Working experience}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i was giving it 2 arguments because of an outdated version :/